# TinyMCE v4 alignright-button doesn't work for iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, tinymce-4

I'm providing a TinyMCE v4-editor for my end customers.
Unfortunately the built-in "alignright"-button doesn't work for videos (iframes). 
Has anybody got an idea how to get iframes aligned to the right with WYSIWYG-Tools only?

I've already tried adding an own custom button for alignright, which should add the class 'alignright' to the selected element:

```
editor.addButton('alignright-custom', {
    text: 'alignright',
    icon: false,
    onclick: function () {
        console.log(tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode());
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.addClass(tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode(), 'alignright');
    }
});
```

However, TinyMCE doesn't add this class to the iframe, but to some weird `<span>` instead, which seems to represent the iframe:

```
<span class="mce-preview-object mce-object-iframe alignright" data-mce-object="iframe" data-mce-p-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/blahblah" data-mce-selected="1" contenteditable="false">
```

The iframe itself won't get affected in any way :/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar problem I created a new tinymce plugin and utilizing the `jquery` I modified the inline style.

As you can see tinymce on an ExecCommand event you can put custom listeners: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/#execcommand Also the event caries the command name just echo it in order to see the correct event.

Also have a look on https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/creating-a-plugin/

You can base your plugin on this piece of code:

```
  tinymce.PluginManager.add('onAlighn',function(editor){

    var elem=undefined

   editor.on('click',function(event){
      var element = event.target;
      //check if iframe 
    })

    editor.on('ExecCommand',function(event){
       if(elem){
         console.log(event)
         //Check furter the event
       }
    })
  })

 })
```